# i get this error in python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python-requests

i trying to get some data from a site no matter what I do, I get this error again  list index out of range

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AMZN?p=AMZN&.tsrc=fin-srch"
header = {'user_agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

html_page = requests.get(url , headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content)

header_info = soup.find_all('div', id="quote-header-info")[0]
stock_title = header_info.find('h1').get_text()
current_price = header_info.find('fin-streamer', class_="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").get_text()
table_info = soup.find('div', class_='D(ib) W(1/2) Bxz(bb) Pend(12px) Va(t) ie-7_D(i) smartphone_D(b) smartphone_W(100%) smartphone_Pend(0px) smartphone_BdY smartphone_Bdc($seperatorColor)').find('table', class_="W(100%)").find_all('tr')
print(table_info)
```

Comment: because the "header_info" is empty hence the index is indeed out of range. 
i suggest you to check the structure of the HTML and see if effectively there is an id as requested.
Please note that just by running the code there are many other errors here and there.